# warning in mkdir and how to display images from the directory created

Tags: php, image, mkdir

My program is supposed to create a folder for the uploaded images on the directory but gives this warning:

> mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in C:\XAMP\xampp\htdocs\gallery\uploader3.php on line 26

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Sample1  - File Upload on Directory </title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<form action="uploader3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
        Create an Album (limited to 10 images): <br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"   />
</form>
</div>
<?php 
$target_path = "uploads1/";
if(!mkdir($target_path))
{
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
else
{
    for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES['uploadedfile']); $count++)
    {
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$count]); 

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$count], $target_path)) 
        {
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$count]). 
        " has been uploaded";
        } 
        else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at once. Thank you. I removed the second question.

Comment: what does it mean when someone edits my question? @mat

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Comment: @SimonCode: don't edit your solution in like that. You must not remove the initial problem from your question, otherwise it becomes sensless.

Comment: @Mat okies.. thanks for that reminder.. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your codes below:

```
if(!mkdir($target_path))
{
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

to:

```
if(!file_exist($target_path)) {
  if(!mkdir($target_path))
  {
      die('Failed to create folders...');
  }
}
```

That will check the folder first, if it's already exist, no need to create it again.

for your 2nd question, you need to store the uploaded image names to somewhere ( i guess DB is a good choice), Then, you can show them anywhere you want.
Or you can use below codes to search in folder and display them:

```
$image_files = glob("uploads1/*.jpg");
foreach($image_files as $img) {
    echo "<img src='".$img."' /><br/>";
}
```

Comment: thank you @BennyHan I shall do that.. and inform you if it did well or not.. thanks for the help. :D

Comment: it creates the folder but doesnt go through the upload process.. no image gets in the target path.. how should I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should check first that the directory does not already exist before attempting to create it

```
if (!file_exists($target_path))
    mkdir($target_path);

if (file_exists($target_path))
{
    // Further processing here
}
else
{
    // Could not create directory
}
```

Comment: @craig1231: Please do not suggest using the `@` operator here on SO. Also suggest to deal with return values.

Comment: @craig1231 it only creates the folder but the images are not uploaded on the folder.. what shall I do?

Comment: @SimonCode, instead of '$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$count]' try '$_FILES['uploadedfile'][$count]['name']'

Comment: @craig1231 why? what's the difference? it works well before i added the mkdir() function.. :)

Comment: @craig1231 it didn't change anything.. the images wont upload at the directory i specified.. T_T